# Which close reason is more appropriate in the following case?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

This close reason was add to the close selection recently:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

Now I would like to know, if this is the appropriate choice to close questions like this one for example?
[Enter specific location on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202324/enter-specific-location-on-screen)

I choose this question because obviously it's a poor question. And as I see it the intention of the OP is "give me the code".

- The problem statement is described in a very weak way.
- There is no effort from OP's side, but the statement "I have used WindowManager for get touch location but can't set it"

But for me it's no debugging question, which is the main focus of the close reason. Usually I would close vote this question with the reason it's "unclear what you're asking". Because it is in the first place.

To clarify my question: Is the new close reason only appropriate if the question is about debugging or should I choose it for questions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use "unclear what you are asking" in this case (or "too broad" at a pinch).

If you want to go into more detail you could use the "off-topic -> other" reason and put in a suitable reason yourself.

The new close reason should only be used on questions where it is about debugging.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would say it is unclear - I'm not sure whether he is trying to set or read the location (although I think he's trying to override the value Windowmanager returns for touch inputs for some reason?). Even if he had been clear about that, he's asking whether something is possible or not.

I suppose that could be worded in a way that makes it a debugging question (if he wrote his question to say "I tried assigning this but it fails" or similar), but as written I'd say stick to unclear - it still asks for clarification / additional details, which is what you would want them to provide in this instance.